# One to one relationship entities of same type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm very new in ASP.NetCore and EF Core.

I'm having troubles to figure out how to handle this situation:

I have a list of **AvailableStudy**, and every study has a list of **AvailableStage**. But also, a stage can depends on a previous stage (but is not mandatory), and the same happens with studies, a study can depends on a previous study. Here are the model classes:

**BusinessObject:**

```
 public class BusinessObject : IBusinessObject
    {
        #region Constructors
        public BusinessObject()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public BusinessObject(string name) :  this()
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        #endregion

        #region IBusinessObject implementation
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

**AvailableStudy:**

```
   public class AvailableStudy : BusinessObject
    {
        #region Constructors
        public AvailableStudy() : base()
        {
            Stages = new List<AvailableStage>();
        }

        public AvailableStudy(string name) : base(name)
        {
            Stages = new List<AvailableStage>();
        }
        #endregion


        [ForeignKey("DependsOn")]
        public string DependsOnId { get; set; }

        #region Lazy-Load Properties
        public virtual List<AvailableStage> Stages { get; set; }

        public virtual AvailableStudy DependsOn { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

**AvailableStage:**

```
public class AvailableStage : BusinessObject
    {
        #region Constructors
        public AvailableStage() : base()
        {
        }

        public AvailableStage(string name) : base(name)
        {
        }

        public AvailableStage(string name, AvailableStudy study) : base(name)
        {
            Study = study;
        }
        #endregion


        #region Properties
        [Required]
        public string StudyId { get; set; }

        public double Percentage { get; set; }

        public int Duration { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DependsOn")]
        public string DependsOnId { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Lazy-Load Properties
        public virtual AvailableStage DependsOn { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StudyId")]
        public virtual AvailableStudy Study { get; set; }
        #endregion        
    }
```

And finally, the OnModelCreating of my context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableStudy>().ToTable("AvailableStudies");
            modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableStudy>().HasMany(i => i.Stages).WithOne(c => c.Study);
           modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableStudy>().HasOne(i => i.DependsOn);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableStage>().ToTable("AvailableStages");
            modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableStage>().HasOne(i => i.Study).WithMany(u => u.Stages);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableStage>().HasOne(i => i.DependsOn);         
        }
```

I'm parsing a JSON file to generate a list of studies with their stages and dependencies.

**A fragment of a JSON file**

```
{
  "Studies": [
    {
      "Name": "Concentrated",
      "DependsOn": "",
      "Stages": [
        {
          "Name": "IsConcentratedDone",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        },
        {
          "Name": "WasDescribed",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        },
        {
          "Name": "HasPhotos",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        },
        {
          "Name": "ReportFinished",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "AFT",
      "DependsOn": "Concentrated",
      "Stages": [
        {
          "Name": "IsMountDone",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        },
        {
          "Name": "SendedToIrradiation",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        },
        {
          "Name": "WasRecepted",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        },
        {
          "Name": "WasMeasured",
          "Percentage": 25,
          "Duration": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, I add this studies to the proper DBSet in DBContext class and when I try to save changes throws an exception that says:

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_AvailableStages_AvailableStages_DependsOnId". The conflict occurred in database "LateAndesSamples", table "dbo.AvailableStages", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

I'm really don't understand what's happening.

Thansk for your help!

The complete exception result is:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at LabManager.DataModel.Data.DbSeeder.CreateStudiesWithStages(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) in W:\LabManager\DataModel\src\Data\DbSeeder.cs:line 113
   at LabManager.DataModel.Data.DbSeeder.Seed(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, RoleManager`1 roleManager, UserManager`1 userManager, IHostingEnvironment env) in W:\LabManager\DataModel\src\Data\DbSeeder.cs:line 22
   at LabManagerWebPage.Extensions.ServiceExtensions.ConfigureDBContext(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in W:\LabManager\LabManagerWebPage\Extensions\ServiceExtensions.cs:line 156
   at LabManagerWebPage.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in W:\LabManager\LabManagerWebPage\Startup.cs:line 107

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_AvailableStages_AvailableStages_DependsOnId". The conflict occurred in database "LateAndesSamples", table "dbo.AvailableStages", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the base class. It needs to be abstract. Otherwise, it's going to create relational inheritance and the only strategy EF Core supports is table-per-hierarchy, AKA single-table inheritance. That means for a seemingly global base class like `BusinessObject`, you'll end up with one huge table with all your other types being stuffed into it. In other words, a mess.

By making it abstract, the derived types will inherit the behavior, but they'll still each get their own tables.

Comment: Thank you for you anwser! Sorry for the noob question, but this is not solved with OnModelCreating method, when calls "modelBuilder.Entity<AvailableStudy>().ToTable("AvailableStudies");"...etc?

Comment: Anyway, I've followed your advice Chirs. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I solved!

I was calling the following methods after parsing JSON file:

```
//availables is a list of availiables studies generated after parsing json file

dbContext.AvailableStudies.AddRange(availables);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But when I looked in details, the stages with no dependencies contains empty string on DependsOnId property, instead of null. After replace empty strings with null, it works fine!